# shell script grep value in variable and renaming file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to bulk renamed file.

I have thousand thousand csv file like tis

```
db_dd.ok.csv
kk_dl.rk.csv
mk_kal.csv
```

and i am trying to rename all these files and the final file name will be these:

```
dd.ok.csv
dl.rk.csv
kal.csv
```

and this is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *.csv
do
    echo $x | grep '([a-zA-Z]+\.csv)'
done
```

My regex working good but i can't run here `mv` command with the value of `grep`, so i tried to put grep value in a variable then i will run `mv` command, i failed.

can anyone help me how can I do this?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `rename` command?

Comment: Why can't you run `mv` with the value of `grep`? Use `$(command)` to substitute the output of a command into the command line. This is one of the most basic shell scripting operations.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: See the linked question. Set a variable `dest` to the command output, then use `mv "$x" "$dest"`

Comment: I dont see any option to asign variable with grep value in foor loop

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't the other question show how to do: `dest=$(echo "$x" | grep ...)`